# Cosa significa "cimentare le vespe" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Fin che l’ex podestà disse chiaro, sui tavolini dell’Angelo, che ai tempi di prima queste cose non succedevano. Allora saltò su il camionista – uno di Calosso, grinta dura – che gli chiese dov’era finito, ai tempi di prima, quello zolfo del Consorzio. 
>         Tornai da Nuto e lo trovai che misurava degli assi, sempre imbronciato. La moglie in casa dava il latte al bambino. Gli gridò dalla finestra ch’era scemo a pigliarsela, che nessuno aveva mai guadagnato niente con la politica. Io per tutto lo stradone, dal paese al Salto, avevo rimuginato queste cose ma non sapevo come dirgli la mia. Adesso Nuto mi guardò, sbatté la riga e mi chiese brusco se non ne avevo abbastanza, che cosa ci trovavo in questi paesacci. 
>         – Dovevate farla allora, – gli dissi, – non è da furbi **cimentare le vespe**.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "cimentare le vespe" in questo brano? Ho cercato il verbo "cimentare" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che vuol dire "mettere alla prova" o "mettere a rischio", ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "cimentare le vespe".

Comment: Dal contesto, sembrerebbe usato nel senso di “stuzzicare, provocare”, che non è poi lontanissimo da “mettere alla prova”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il commento di @DaG dà la soluzione corretta. Prendo la definizione di *cimento* dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cimento/):

> fig. Prova pericolosa, rischio: *tentare il c. delle armi; essere,
>   mettersi, trovarsi in un grave c.*;

In questo caso *cimentare* significa appunto *sfidare* o *stuzzicare* .

Si potrebbe utilizzare un'espressione simile, ovvero *"stuzzicare il vespaio"* (sempre da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vespaio/))

> *stuzzicare il v*., eccitare il risentimento di persone irritabili o provocare malumori, pettegolezzi e discussioni, polemiche: *di che si andava impacciando ora egli? che vespaio gli veniva in mente di stuzzicare?* (Serao); e *suscitare, sollevare un v*., provocare pettegolezzi, diatribe, complicazioni, malumori, risentimenti.

Nel [Grande dizionario della lingua italiana](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_819.pdf&parola=cimentare) viene riportato alla voce "Vespa":

> 7. Locuz. *Attizzare, cimentare, stuzzicare le vespe*. provocare e suscitare guai, conflitti, contrasti, fastidi pericolosi, per lo più
>      senza necessità

Nel [Nuovo De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cimentare) viene indicato come significato di "*cimentare*":

> mettere a dura prova, sfidare: *cimentare la pazienza di qcn.* |
>   provocare: *cimentare qcn.*

Un sentito grazie a @Charo e @Benedetta per i riferimenti!

Comment: Nonostante abbia proposto questa interpretazione, me ne sentirei più sicuro se trovassimo qualche altro esempio dello stesso uso.

Comment: @DaG: L'ho appena trovato sul [Grande dizionario della lingua italiana](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_819.pdf&parola=cimentare): «*7.* Locuz. - *Attizzare, cimentare, stuzzicare le vespe*-.
provocare e suscitare guai, conflitti, contrasti, fastidi pericolosi, per lo più senza necessità.» Riccardo: Potresti includere questa fonte nella tua risposta?

Comment: Nel Nuovo De Mauro uno dei significati, figurato, è «sfidare, provocare» (https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cimentare): penso possa essere utilizzato come riferimento.

Comment: @DaG:  Sul *Grande dizionario* si possono leggere un esempio di Ariosto di "attizzar le vespe" e un altro di Monosini di "stuzzicare le vespe".

Comment: Ottimo, @Charo, grazie!